# How to position a textInput widget on certain position in a shiny app with a background picture

Tags: r, shiny, css-position, background-image

I have this example app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  textInput("a", "A", width = 20),
  textInput("b", "B", width = 20),
  tags$img(
    src = "https://posit.co/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/09_HOMEPAGE.svg",
 style = 'position: absolute'
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which creates this:
[image]

**How can I position the textInput widgets like this way:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order to have the image first with static sizing then embed the input in a `div` with absolute position:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  tags$img(
    src = "https://posit.co/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/09_HOMEPAGE.svg",
    style = 'position: absolute; width: 1024px; height: 768px;'
  ),
  tags$div( 
    textInput("a", "A", width = 20),
    style = 'position: absolute;left: 420px; top: 100px;'),
)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Is it possible to keep the textInput always the same position related to the background picture? Now by changing the window size the textInput moves around.

Comment: FYI - if you resize the browser the input will lose the correct positioning

Comment: @TarJae - you could update the left and top to use percentages instead of pixels but it still doesn't track accurately from my testing. I think you'll need to use JS in order to set the position properly with x,y coords.

Comment: Any idea for a source?

Comment: Easier to set the image as not resizable `position: absolute; width: 1024px; height: 768px;`

Comment: Could please update your answer with this valuable comment?